# How to make a Socket.IO app to Heroku

Tags: javascript, heroku, socket.io

I want to make a little mmo game in js, i found socket.io and heroku, but i don't know how use them in one project.

How can I use socket.io on heroku?

PS.:
I didn't know a lot about it, so I wanted to found a tutorial which is "step by step"

Sorry for my English, I just learn it.

Comment: This is kind of a vague question. Heroku is a hosting platform, on which you can run a variety of different types of web servers. SocketIO is a JavaScript library for real-time server-client communication. So first you'd need to be a web hosting technology, like NodeJS or Ruby on Rails, and then you'd want to integrate SocketIO with one of those. Once you have developed your web application, you could then deploy it on Heroku. SocketIO's own website has a decent tutorial for getting started on NodeJS: http://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Comment: I know it, but If I use socket.io in my apllication, which has uploaded to heroku. It makes an error.

I didn't found any example program, or a good tutroial to build an app to heroku which use socket.io

Comment: What is the error? And how are you including the SocketIO library?

Comment: I know it isn't going to work, but I tried to just upload it, like a normal program.
How can I include it?

Thanks for your patience...

Comment: You should be able to just include this script tag at the top of whatever web page you want to user socket.IO:

`<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.0.js"></script>`